# Loop a component in React

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, components

```
import Favcheck from "./favcheck.jsx";
export default function Mensbuttons() {
  const list1 = ["test1","name1"];
  const list2 = ["test2","name2"];
  const list = [];
  list.push(list1,list2);

  return (
    
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

    <>
      <div class="formcontainer">
        <form method="get" action="/mensapage" class="mensaform">
          <button type="submit" class="mensabutton">
            <div class="mensatext"> {list[i][0]</div>
          </button>
          <Favcheck />
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  }
  );
  
}
```

So I'm really sure thats not how its done but I have no idea how I would do it differenty. So I have a component in react and I want to loop throw an array with arrays. In order to create a button with a name of an element of the array inside the parentarray. Im not sure where I should insert the for-loop. I would appreciate an answer.

Comment: Use `map` instead of a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code to use map.

```js
import React from "react";

export default function Mensbuttons() {
  const list1 = ["test1","name1"];
  const list2 = ["test2","name2"];
  const list = [];
  list.push(list1,list2);

  return (
    <>
      <div class="formcontainer">
        <form method="get" action="/mensapage" class="mensaform">
          {list.map(item => 
            (<button type="submit" name={item[1]} class="mensabutton">
              <div class="mensatext">{item[0]}</div>
            </button>
            )
          )}
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
  
}
```

But I suggest you to set like following to use name instead of index.

```js
[
  { label: "name1", value: "test1" },
  { label: "name2", value: "test2" }
]
```

```js
import React from "react";

export default function Mensbuttons() {
  const listNew = [
    { label: "name1", value: "test1" },
    { label: "name2", value: "test2" }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <div class="formcontainer">
        <form method="get" action="/mensapage" class="mensaform">
          {listNew.map(item => 
            (<button type="submit" name={item.label} class="mensabutton">
              <div class="mensatext">{item.value}</div>
            </button>
            )
          )}
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
  
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1cwpnl?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

```js
export default function Mensbuttons() {
  const list1 = ["test1", "name1"];
  const list2 = ["test2", "name2"];
  const list = [];
  list.push(list1, list2);

  return (
    <>
      <div class="formcontainer">
        <form method="get" action="/mensapage" class="mensaform">
          {list.map((data) =>
            data.map((item) => (
              <button type="submit" class="mensabutton">
                <div class="mensatext"> {item}</div>
              </button>
            ))
          )}
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use *map* method. notice that you have to set a *key* attribute for elements in loop.

```
import Favcheck from "./favcheck.jsx";
export default function Mensbuttons() {
  const list1 = ["test1","name1"];
  const list2 = ["test2","name2"];
  const list = [];
  list.push(list1,list2);

  return (
    <>
    {list.map(innerArray => 
      innerArray.map(item => <div key={item} class="formcontainer">
        <form method="get" action="/mensapage" class="mensaform">
          <button type="submit" class="mensabutton">
            <div class="mensatext">{item}</div>
          </button>
          <Favcheck />
        </form>
      </div>))}
     </>
  );
  
}
```